# Using initialized String in asynchronous anonymous function in another page

Tags: flutter, dart, parameter-passing

how can you use `String theFlag` anywhere else outside of this anonymous function

I had to make it an anonymous function as I failed to point a separate  asynchronous function into `onPressed` in a `RaisedButton` as it only worked with `onChanged` now i just need to pass `String theFlag` to another widget in another screen

please help and mind the beginner question

```
  onPressed:() async {
       Locale _temp = await setLocale(LanguageClass.languageList()[index].langCode);
       BldrsApp.setLocale(context, _temp);
    
       String theFlag = LanguageClass.languageList()[index].langFlag ; //I need to use this elsewhere
            print(theFlag);
   },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
String iCanBeAcessed; //make this variable somewhere else, so that you can use it anywhere.
//Inside your anonymous function
 iCanBeAcessed=theFlag;
```

How can i use that?

You can declare it outside a class, and can use it anywhere in your project.
Example,

```
//imports

String iCanBeAcessed;

class yourClassName{
//All your other functions and build method
```

Now, import the dart file( where you have declared the iCanBeAcessed ) in the following manner.

```
import dartFile.dart as flagString;

//Now, you can use this variable anywhere!

Text(flagString.iCanBeAcessed),
```

Comment: Please upvote and accept this as the answer if it helped :)

Comment: thanks for the solution,,

i put iCanBeAcessed in a setState method to change its value according to some button tap and it changes that flag correctly,,

but when you go back to the previous screen, the previous screen is not rebuilt, but the iCanBeAcessed value is updated properly and you can still print it,, 

I can't figure out how to make the previous screens rebuild automatically with the new value assigned to iCanBeAcessed as it keeps the old value of that variable!!?